# USCG Port State Information Exchange API Usage

Tags: c#, asmx

I'm trying to get the USCG Port State Information Exchange API working and am having no luck so far.  I also can find nearly zero information about the service online.

There's the main USCG Page:

https://cgmix.uscg.mil/XML/Default.aspx

And the ASMX / WSDL:

https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx

https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL

The method I'm trying to use is getVesselSummary.  The API looks straightforward enough to use but so far I can only get an empty response back. So at this point I'm wondering if it requires authentication of some sort, even though I've not seen any mention of that online.

I added their WSDL to Visual Studio as a web reference and the Proxy Classes built fine.

I've tried filling in some of the parameters, only one of the parameters.  The result is always the same (screenshot below):

```
var vs = new uscg.psix.PSIXData();
var data = vs.getVesselSummary("650617", "CITY OF CHICAGO", "WDC2646", "", "", "UNITED STATES", "", "1982");
```

[image]

I know this ship exists because I can find it with the same search criteria using their online interface:

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

The SOAP/XML that the Visual Studio Web Reference client creates is apparently the problem.  When I connect to the service with Soap UI and create a request that way it returns data.

So now the question is how do I get Visual Studio / C# to return markup that this service likes?

**This works (Soap UI)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cgm="http://cgmix.uscg.mil">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cgm:getVesselSummary>
         <cgm:VesselID>650617</cgm:VesselID>
         <cgm:VesselName></cgm:VesselName>
         <cgm:CallSign></cgm:CallSign>
         <cgm:VIN></cgm:VIN>
         <cgm:HIN></cgm:HIN>
         <cgm:Flag></cgm:Flag>
         <cgm:Service></cgm:Service>
         <cgm:BuildYear></cgm:BuildYear>
      </cgm:getVesselSummary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**This does NOT Work - Visual Studio's Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <getVesselSummary xmlns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil">
      <VesselID>650617</VesselID>
      <VesselName>
      </VesselName>
      <CallSign>
      </CallSign>
      <VIN>
      </VIN>
      <HIN>
      </HIN>
      <Flag>
      </Flag>
      <Service>
      </Service>
      <BuildYear>
      </BuildYear>
    </getVesselSummary>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response? You can see this by handling the exception and looking at  `(HttpWebResponse) ex.Response;` where `ex` is of type `System.Net.WebException`. That should give more clues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was two-fold.

One:  Even though I entered the WSDL address into the add web reference dialog using https, Visual Studio in its infinite wisdom decided to store it with http.

Two:  There is some sort of certificate error on the Coast Guard site.  So I needed to add a handler for `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to ignore that.

Full code of my test page that I'm dumping in here so I can move on.  Don't forget the using statements!:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CGIX_2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyCertHandler;

            try
            {
                var sr = new mil.uscg.psix.PSIXData();
                var data = sr.getVesselSummaryXMLString("", "A STEVE CROWLEY", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        static bool MyCertHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
        {
            // Ignore errors
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```